# Android Email application dropping profile

Tags: email, exchange

I use my Android with Microsoft Exchange for synchronizing my work email. Every few weeks or so, when I click on 'Email' it asks me to setup my email profile again.

It also stops me from sending photos via Email, etc.

Any idea whats causing this to happen? Usually I end up deleting the profile and recreating, but that sucks.

Comment: Is your work email a Gmail account, or Exchange, etc? Which email app are you using?

Comment: are you using some kind of cleaner or anything else ?

Comment: Sometimes misbehaving apps need to have their data cleared out and a fresh start. Go to Menu -> Settings -> Manage Applications -> Email (or whatever app you are using.) Click on "Clear Data." Try setting up the profile again. If that doesn't work, you may have memory issues as already indicated. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This happened repeatedly to me, I'm not entirely sure why.

What worked for me was to do a "Clear data" (in the Applications screen) on the Email app. When I recreated the profile the next time, it stuck. It may not work for you, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your phone might not have enough storage space.